# multiboot usb not detected by uefi bios

Tags: dual-boot

I'm creating a multiboot usb that's uefi enabled. however, my pc bios is NOT detecting the usb at startup so I can't even run multiboot. Not sure why this is, but can someone explain to me why this is occurring? I'm using YUMI (beta) to create my usb stick and YUMI is UEFI enabled...or supposed to be.

Comment: Is your USB set as first hard drive in BIOS? For YUMI you can format the drive FAT32, (4GB persistence limit), or NTFS, (unlimited persistence).

Comment: It's formatted as FAT32. The thing is that BIOS doesn't even SHOW the USB drive as an option unless I convert the drive to MBR. Then it shows up as a possible drive to boot from.

Answer (score 0):

Format that USB in FAT32 format, try a different writter to make your USB bootable. When PC is starting enter your BIOS settings, if it still doesn't detect maybe the problem is the USB. Have you tried different USB drives?

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing for other USB drives. UEFI/BIOS just doesn't detect my USB unless I use MBR instead of GPT partitioning. When I use MBR partitioning, then UEFI/BIOS detects my USB flash drive and lets me indicate that bootx64.efi is Secure Boot enabled. If it's GPT, the BIOS screen doesn't even DETECT the drive so I can't even override secure boot settings.